# pass boot parameters from grub command line "manual" boot

Tags: boot, command-line, grub2

There are lots of articles and Q&A's about booting/recovering linux distros like ubuntu, et al  from the grub command line. I'm familiar with:

```
set root=(hdX,gptY)
linux /boot/vmlinuz[proper version here] root=/dev/sdaQ
initrd /boot/initrd.img[proper version here]
boot
```

...but where do I add boot parameters, ie "nomodeset"?

This is using Ubuntu 20.10 and grub is v2, I believe.

Comment: `root=/dev/sdaQ` did you try adding `nomodeset` after that??

Comment: In the second image from this post https://askubuntu.com/a/38834/739431 It seems to be. After vmlinuz they are the options